# Typeof value of function value/name logs as "Undefined" . Why?

Tags: javascript, function, object

In the following function typeof(var2) logs as "undefined", whereas I expected it to be a function or a variable.

```
var add_nos = function()    {
    var x = 2+3;
    console.log(x);

}
var var2 = add_nos();
console.log(typeof(var2));
console.log(typeof(add_nos));
```

Can somebuddy pls explain, Why is that so ?

Comment: You're not returning anything from the function which is why `var2` is `undefined`. Not sure why you'd think it would be a function unless you think `var var2 = add_nos()` is _copying_ the function to a new variable.

Comment: For `var2` to equal the actual function, you'd have to set it without the parenthesis like this: `var var2 = add_nos`

Comment: Also, if you `typeof` anything, it will never return saying it's a variable. All a variable is is a container that holds things like strings, arrays, functions, etc. The variable itself isn't a type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing to remember is that functions in JavaScript always return a value. The explicit case is when you include the `return` statement in your function and decide what to return. However, when you don't explicitly include a `return` statement in your function, JavaScript will return the value `undefined`.

Like others have mentioned, your function returns the `undefined` value because there is no explicit return statement in it. The variable `var2` contains this `undefined` value. Therefore, your first `typeof` statement asks what the type of `undefined` is - which is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning the return value of `add_nos()` to `var2`. Since it doesn't have any explicit return value, it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

`var var2 = add_nos();`

`add_nos()` returns `undefined` implicitly, that's why `console.log(typeof(var2));` prints `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

What your u need to do is add a line to your function that looks like this `return x;` that will then return the value of x to whatever called the function. Allowing you to use functions in your calculations. Every function returns a value the thing is that if you don't define what it is to return it returns undefined you're function Ran just fine it just didn't have a value specified to be a return value.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a function, it returns something that you decided to return but it you did not returned any value explicitly then it will return `undefined` which in this case was assigned to var2. Some other languages do similar. e.g. python returns `None` in such case